# Error: spawn ENOENT in meteor mup deploy

Tags: meteor

i successfully deploy my meteor app on amazon EC2 but in next day when i deploy again that time it is not working. it's give me error like

Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)

any help?